# SSIS DataFlow error when inserting a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, ssis

I'm not being able to transfer some SQL-MySQL data using SSIS.
I've done the same thing with other packages for different tables but this time I can't.

Here's a screenshot, data is being retrieved absolutely fine from the SQL server.
[image]

And here's a shoot if the progress tab.

[image]

First error shown in the Progress tab is as follows:

```
[dest mysql [190]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message         returned from the provider is: 
ERROR [23000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.16]You have an error in your SQL               syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"persona_id",    "franqueos", "reiteros", "pcrc_id", "fecha") VALUES (55, 12, 1, 1,' at line 1
```

I'm not sure on how to approach the situation in order to solve it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MySQL database needs to have the `ANSI_QUOTES SQL_MODE` option enabled. Or check whether `null` is  allowed on columns, particularity for `fecha` field in your mysql database table.

Have a look of this as well: [Workaround  - Writing to a MySQL database from SSIS Bug](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/01/07/writing-to-a-mysql-database-from-ssis.aspx)

Comment: I forgot to say I do have that option enabled. That comes right before the DataFlow. But the issue was in the RetainSameConnection property. Thanks!